# Angular 2 - Handling true hash links

Tags: angular

This is actually reloading the page...

```
<div class="el1">
     Yesterday | <a href="#today">Today</a> | Tomorrow
</div>

<div class="rowDate" [attr.id]="b.isToday ? 'today' : null">
...
</div>
```

Is there a solution to make this scroll to the ID like an usual HTML page ?

ty !

Comment: I solved my situation with this: <a onclick="document.getElementById('today').scrollIntoView();">Today</a> - but I will leave this topic open in case if someone post something more elegant and more "angular 2"